# Photoshop Variables - Could not parse the file contents as a dataset.

Tags: dataset, photoshop

i made the award shield template, I have tons of name, every names have their shield(for distribution in annual Exam)... so i defined the variable but when ever i connect variables to the .txt file it shows me this error:

> Could not parse the file contents as a dataset. there were too many variable names in the first line of the text file.[image: Image of my txt file]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, couldn't find what was wrong. Turns out, in 2020, Photoshop only accepts CSV files with a comma as a delimiter. Numbers, the Excel from Apple, only exports CSVs with a semi-column as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

[image]Microsoft Excel Adds ESC character instead of comma (,) when saving csv files. so you must replace all ESC characters   with , and save as csv file again .photoshop imports it  and work correctly and if you check replace existing data set option you could dynamically change text values in your graphic files.
save csv file from excel and open it via notepad++ to see that ESC character i mentioned.
open csv file in notepad++ and select that character with mouse then copy and replace all with comma (,).dont do this by ctrl + c .
for dynamic editing text and pixel variables you maust do import file anytime.